# Windows 10 Enterprise: Plays an annoying sound every minute with okay, but less than perfect connections

Tags: windows, kvm-switch

Windows 10 Enterprise HP Laptop

I have a Windows 10 Enterprise HP Laptop attached to a pure hardware KVM switch.

I think the cables are getting old.

At first Windows started complaining about there being no Internet connection.  If I removed and reinserted the ethernet cable all was well.

Now I get an annoying music/noise every minute.

If I unplugged all of the cables from the KVM it stops.

I'm guessing the cables are less than perfect or slightly worn out.

They still work.

I'm going to order a new KVM, but can anyone tell me the name of that noise so I can mute it until the new KVM arrives?

Comment: Is it *Windows*, or is it the software run by the KVM switch, making that sound? What software are you using?

Comment: It is a pure hardware KVM.  Also I had the KVM completely disconnected and the sounds persisted.  I used the KVM cables.  When I switched to device ( keyboard mouse, ethernet ) cables directly the sounds stopped.   So it is the KVM cables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your system settings for "sound" and "system sounds." Within that section, you should be able to locate Device Connect and Device Disconnect and set the audio to none. When you correct the cable problems, you may want to return the settings for those entries to default, therefore make a note before you disable them.

Comment: That worked thank you.
Everything is functioning.  No annoying noises every few seconds.

Comment: If you find the answer satisfactory, please select the check mark to accept the answer and to further inflate my ego.